# "Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement lbcapi (from versions: )" when trying to install via pip

Tags: pip

When I try to install the PyPI module lbcapi (`sudo pip install lbcapi`), I encounter the following message:

```
Collecting lbcapi
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement lbcapi (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for lbcapi
```

What could be going wrong? I'm seeing this for Python 2 and Python 3.

Answer (score 1):

Running `pip download lbcapi` works for me (for Python 2).
But there's no Python 3 compatible version of lbcapi of [PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/lbcapi/#files), so installing it on Python 3 is a bit more tricky.

[It doesn't look like this software is compatible with Python 3.](https://github.com/LocalBitcoins/lbcapi/issues/1)

Answer (score 0):

I uninstalled the older pip and installed the newest version `10.0.0` by entering this:

```
python3 -m pip uninstall pip setuptools
curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py | python3
```

Now my problem was solved. If you are using the python2, you can substitute the python3 with python. I hope it also works for you.
(copied the answer from Stack Overflow)

Comment: You should link the original answer, so we can go there and upvote.